# Is it possible to create a web browser using assembly

Tags: assembly, browser

Would it be possible to write a web browser entirely in assembly? If so, how exactly would this be accomplished? From what I've read online, it would use the 15h Interupt, but other than that I haven't found any other information. I'm mostly wondering out of curiosity, and have no ambition to attempt such a difficult project, but any information on this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: You should start with `asm.js`.

Answer (score 13):

Of course it's possible to create a Web browser or any other software in assembly language. After all, regardless of what language a program is written in, ultimately there are machine instructions that execute it. And assembly language is nothing more than human-readable machine instructions. So, yes, it's quite possible to write a Web browser in assembly language.

Whether you'd want to is another thing entirely.

Answer (score 4):

Creating of web browser in assembly language is possible of course. There was several attempts, some of them more or less successful.

[MenuetOS 64bit](http://menuetos.org) has browser inside, as the author state, written in assembly language. Unfortunately, the project is closed source, so it can't be checked.

[KolibriOS](http://www.kolibrios.org) has lightweight browser (pretty feature limited though).

The main problem with such projects is that there are not enough people to work on them. Generally the assembly programmers have different interests and they are too few these days to waste its time for web browser programming.

Comment: Shouldn't this say "too few"? There's just not enough use in this. The expected performance improvement (if any) does by no means outweight the extra effort.

Comment: @PMF - It is not so simple. It is very long talk, but definitely not suitable for comments under an answer on SO.